# IIS 10.0 HTTP 404 - Not Found - MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-10

MVC 5 application working fine on local system.
When I deploy the application on Production server (Windows server 2016 Standard), Login page loads successfully but after sign in it throw HTTP 404 Not Found error.

Login Page URL: `http://localhost/LP`

LP is application name.

Application throw error on URL :

```
http://localhost/Home/LoginAuth
```

LoginAuth is post method. Application name (LP) is missing.

I have already tried below solution:

1. `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

Set the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true. This didn't work for me

2. Solution given on link : 
   [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563584/iis-10-0-detailed-error-404-0-for-httpdelete-httpput)
3. Installed almost everything.

[image: IIS Setting]

4. Application Pool

   [image: Application Pool]

None of the solution is working. Please suggest.

This is error message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: it seems you have hard coded domain name in form tag e.g. do not use urls starting with '/'

Comment: can you show your form tag

Comment: @NitinSawant Thanks Nitin. You are right. This was form tag issue. I have replaced form tag with MVC BeginForm method. Now it is working fine.